# Redirect frame to https?

Tags: php, html, css, redirect

I'm using a frame code on my page www.interimincomemodel.info but when it comes to a part on a video 3 when a framed page is supposed to bring a user to a Google page, Firerox shows just a blank page and IE says that "can't show the content in a frame".

I've found that a frame can't show https content. So my question is, what should I put in my code to make the frame to redirect to a Google page?

How do I instruct a browser using html so that when a user clicks on a link say https://www.google.com the content have not be shown in the frame but must redirect the domain to https://www.google.com ?

Is there any sort of code to do that?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
    <meta name="VERSION" content="">
    <meta name="DATA" content="">
    <link href="http://www.interimincomemodel.info/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Interim Income Model</title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows='100%' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
    <frame src="http://interimincomemodel.com/reps/eugeny/" name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=8 marginwidth=0></frame>
    </frameset>
    <noframes><h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your
    browser.</h2><br><br>
    <center>Click <a href="http://interimincomemodel.com/reps/eugeny/" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
    </noframes>
    </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering why you opened a new account. What happened with previous one?

Comment: I didn't open a new account. It's an old one. Why is this question? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: just wondering. I answered a question about this same site a couple days ago, so it's not like I forgot about it. Also, there wasn't any issue with that site, so just wondering

Comment: I just found out this bug right now and looking for a solution. It is very important to have a fully working site before starting to spend on traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Google's web sites have the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header set, which prevents them from being displayed in frames. This cannot be overridden — you will need to find an alternate solution, such as linking to the site instead of trying to frame it.

(The fact that the site you're trying to frame is being loaded over HTTPS is a red herring.)

Comment: Right, I've actually asked for a code that would redirect my entire domain to a Google's page only when a user clicks on that particular google link. Just as it was a sort of html condition like: "if user clicks on a google link - then don't show google in the frame, but instead redirect the entire domain to a google page". Is there any code like that? Sort of conditional?

Comment: You don't need any code for that. A normal HTML link will do what you're describing.

Comment: How to do that? If I want a user to be redirected from my domain to https://www.google.com when it clicks on that link on the original domain that is framed into mine, how can I do this?

Comment: By setting the `target` attribute appropriately on the link.

Comment: This is the original page http://interimincomemodel.com/reps/eugeny/index3a.php where is the link to google. When you click on the button at the bottom "NO I do not accept this" it takes you to a google's page. But this link on the original site is between the <srtipt></script> tags. What do I need to set target to in this case?